# «Мыть голову» и «мыть волосы»

Tags: стилистика, выбор-слов

Я вижу — здесь этот вопрос ещё не задавался. Почему, собственно, люди говорят «мыть голову», когда мы не моем голову? Мы ведь волосы моем. Правомерна ли такая лексическая сочетаемость? Может, разговорный литературный язык допускает такое словосочетание (хотя я в этом глубоко заблуждаюсь)? Везде можно услышать такое, поэтому уже накипело. Эта ситуация схожа с тем случаем, когда мы говорим «открыть форточку». Эту команду мы воспринимаем очень просто, не задумываясь. Возможно, здесь свою функцию выполняют ассоциации. И всё-таки что считать правильным, а что — неправильным?

Comment: Я много раз пытался избежать попадания шампуня на мой скальп, когда я мыл волосы, но каждый раз у меня не получалось.  Так что, собираясь вымыть только волосы, я всё равно мыл всю голову...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Шутка (смайлик)

"Почему, собственно, люди говорят «мыть голову», когда мы не моем голову? Мы ведь волосы моем".  А если у человека нет волос, то он моет голову по привычке. И если собака, то как сказать: мы собаку моем или шерсть? А вот промывают мозги (brainwash) почему-то отдельно от головы, но в то же время "намыливают" только голову:

"Сердце у него так и ёкнуло: он привык, что его вызывали только за тем, чтобы намылить голову — неужели он опять в чём-нибудь провинился? (Т. Щепкина-Куперник. Театр в моей жизни).

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

Я думаю, что дело не в частных причинах загрязнения, просто мы моем   тело или различные части тела (голову, руки) вместе со всем, что к этим частям  относится, не их упоминая отдельно.

В то же время ничего не мешает нам сказать, что мы моем волосы, например:

Хоть я и обожаю этот ее опьяняющий каштановый запах, все же мне кажется, что ей бы следовало кое-когда **вымыть волосы** (В. В. Набоков. Лолита).

Она сидела в кресле и негромко, но сердито говорила, что вот уже десять дней не может найти часа, чтобы **вымыть волосы** (Илья Ильф, Евгений Петров).

Answer (score 0):

Основная и банальная причина загрязнения волос (кроме влияния воздушной среды и грязного головного убора) — выделения кожи головы. Так что правильнее говорить именно о мытье головы.

Answer (score 0):

Все шампуни для волос (жирных, сухих) и т. д. Для головы шампуней нет.

Comment: Вопрос не о средстве. Скорее уж о форточке.

Answer (score 0):

Выделения из сальных желез головы, но моем-то волосы!

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://rus.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://rus.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). — [из очереди проверок](/review/late-answers/39932)